# Django: reference the previous form while looping through a FormSet

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm looping through a FormSet in my template:

```
{% for interval in form %}
  {% if forloop.counter > 1 %}
    <here I do things>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

For some JavaScript initialization reasons, I need to get a reference to the previous form. I can do that explicitly this way:

```
form.0.my_field.value
```

But how can I do that in my loop so I get the previous form?

Comment: I think you should share your "JavaScript intialization reasons". There's very likely a better way to achieve what you want.

Comment: It's a little bit confusing, but there we go: The forms in the formset are date intervals. I must initalize a javascript datepicker for each interval, and not allow it to select an init date earlier than the previous interval init date.